# How to receive the numbers dialled by a caller during a call in Android using Telephony Manager

Tags: android

I want to receive the numbers dialled by a caller during a call in Android using Telephony Manager. It's basically like costumer care where they ask us to dial a number and respond accordingly

Comment: Did you try something? Include that also

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is **NOT Possible**.

Basically when you make a call, you are connected to a Service provider and in turn to the receiver. Our actions (key press) can be monitored by the service provider, but not for the receiver. Because it is the service provider who decides which signals should be reached at receiver. If such a signal(data) is provided, then the research is feasible.